# Object Tracking on Image

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, tracking, object-detection

I'm using [TF API for object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) to detect an object in my video stream. The issue is that even with mobile model, detecting object at every frame slows the video speed. So I was wondering if I can detect the object once and keep tracking it rest of the period. But unfortunately I could not figure out how to do it. I tried opencv tracking APIs, but having issue in tracking the same object over the entire time period. If someone can guide me, it will be of great help.

Thank you!

My working code:

```
# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

sess = tf.Session(graph = detection_graph)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("someVide.mp4")
while(cap.isOpened()):
     ret, frame = cap.read()
     if ret == True:
          frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections] = [detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0'), \
        detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0'), detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0'), \
        detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')]
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run([boxes, scores, classes, num_detections], \
            feed_dict = {image_tensor: frame_expanded})

        b = vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)
   else:
      break
```

Comment: opencv 3 has a TLD implementation.

Comment: @Micka: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried all 3-4 options given in opencv. As the code shows I'm detecting the object, say do. Then I'm putting the tracker. But in the next frame again the object is getting detected and the tracker values changes. So I want to detect it once, put and ID to it so that detection will not get repeated again for that particular dog. If there's some other dog, it will again detect. But that I could not figure out how to do.

Comment: if detection is in the same area as your current tracked object: Don't add the new object to tracking, instead assume that it is the same as before and already tracked.

Comment: @Micka: The dog is actually moving. I detect a dog in the first frame and then want to track the dog till the end of the frame. But if another do of similar kind comes up, it will detect that second dog and then again track it. So it will not remain in the same area across all the time.

Comment: so TLD Tracker didn't work to track the dog? Try to implement a simple HSV color model particle filter tracker yourself.

Comment: Thanks Micka! I'll try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: @Micka: Is there's a way to check if the dog is getting tracked in the image or not. So the idea is, I'll create a loop. In the first case, the image will detect the dog and track it. If the dog is tracked the I'll not run any detection. But if its not, I'll run the detection algorithm again. But for that I need to know if it's already getting tracked or not. Is there any way to check if an image is already getting tracked or not?